# Exporting data from dev_appserver

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm testing a schema change over two versions of my app. I used version 1 to generate test data, and now I'd like to take that data into version 2 to run and test the converter.  This is easy enough to do live on appengine, since the datastore stays persistent between versions, but I'm finding that local_db.bin does not survive from one version to the next (maybe this is because the version of the sdk also changes between versions).

I'd like to use appcfg.py to download_data from dev_appserver and then upload_data to the new version, but it seems to be asking me to download each kind of entity individually ("Kind stats are not available on dev_appserver.").

I can write a script that iterates through all of my kinds to use download_ and upload_data. Is there an easier way to transfer data between instances of the dev server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One unelegant solution:

bash script to pump data out:

```
KINDS="Assessment AssessmentScore Course GradingPeriod GradingPolicy OverallGradeDefinition Standard StandardTag User"
for KIND in $KINDS
do
    echo "ugh" | appcfg.py download_data --filename=$KIND --kind=$KIND -email=blagh --url=http://localhost:8888/remote_api --passin --application=myapp
    sleep 5
done
```

And a corresponding script with upload_data to pump it back in.  Getting pretty kludgy when you're using bash to drive python to drive http requests to your java app!